# Static in a DLL is initialized and then not anymore

Tags: c++, dll

I am encountering a very strange issue in my code... I've spent now a whole afternoon and cannot get nor heads nor tails on it. But maybe someone here can point me what I'm doing wrong.

So for the explanation:

I have a DLL.

In it I have 2 classes:

```
class Plugin {
public:
    Plugin() : isInited(false) { all_plugins.push_back(this); }
    virtual ~Plugin() { }

    virtual int OnInit(ONINIT_PARAMS)       { return 0; }
    virtual void OnDeInit(ONDEINIT_PARAMS)  { }
    virtual int OnTick(ONTICK_PARAMS)       { return 0; }

private:
    static std::vector<Plugin*> all_plugins;

private: // NO COPY CLASS
    Plugin(const Plugin&);
    const Plugin& operator=(const Plugin&);
};
```

This class is responsible for mapping the Init/DeInit/Tick function-calls which comes from the main application.

Secondly I have this:

```
class DynamicModule {
public:
    DynamicModule() : isLoaded(false) { all_modules.push_back(this); }
    virtual ~DynamicModule() { }

    virtual int OnLoad()   { return 0; };
    virtual int OnUnload() { return 0; };

private:
    static std::vector<DynamicModule*> all_modules;

private: // NO COPY CLASS
    DynamicModule(const DynamicModule&);
    const DynamicModule& operator=(const DynamicModule&);
};

#define IMPLEMENT_DYNAMICMODULE std::vector<DynamicModule*> DynamicModule::all_modules;
```

Now in plugin.cpp I do:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMICMODULE;
std::vector<Plugin*> Plugin::all_plugins;
```

That takes care of the static stuff.

Now I define a class (in a header file):

```
class InMarket : public Plugin {
public:
    int OnInit   (ONINIT_PARAMS);
    void OnDeInit(ONDEINIT_PARAMS);
    int OnTick   (ONTICK_PARAMS);

private:
};
```

And implement it in a C++ file:

```
static class InMarket _InMarket;
```

I traced it, and the constructor gets called correctly. And inserted into Plugin::all_plugins.

Then I continue tracing, and I see the modules (2 at the moment, defined for example like the next example [in a C++ file]):

```
static class MQL4Trade : public DynamicModule {
public:
    virtual int OnLoad() {
        __OrderSend   = (_OrderSend)GetProcAddress(exe, "OrderSend");
        __OrdersCount = (_OrdersCount)GetProcAddress(exe, "OrdersCount");
        return 0;
    }
} _MQL4Trade;
```

I see these modules get inserted as well nicely in DynamicModule::all_modules.
But at the same time when I see this, I also noticed the Plugin::all_plugins has a {size=0}?!

Then when I enter my OnInit() function, I see that all_modules has a size of 2, and all_plugins = 0. Even though ALL of the constructors had been called?

I load my library as:

```
HMODULE plugin = LoadLibrary(pluginFilename.c_str());
```

All static objects constructors are called....
And I don't see ANY differences between the 2 things.

What is going on here?

Comment: Every plugin has its own *all_modules* variable.  They cannot link plugin.cpp.  There must be only one, it belongs in the host.

Comment: @HansPassant The _all_modules_ variable is a static variable defined in DynamicModule. as for the define. I just need to put it somewhere in a C++ file. I put it in Plugin.cpp, of course I could create a DynamicModule.cpp and put it in there, but that wouldn't matter at all no?